# Dynamic approach in Azure SQL DW to get only those column names from a table whose values are not null for a particular record

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

I have the table structure something like below

[image]

Number Of Columns are more than 150.
Basically, I would want to query the table for a particular record say ID = 1 and It should return all column names which are not empty.

I am expecting the below output where in I should be able to fetch/show only those column names whose values are not null for a particular record.

[image]

Kindly note that I am trying to achieve this in Azure SQL DW that doesn't support FOR XML Path clause, Cursor, very limited dynamic SQL functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) works, and you don't have to filter because "null values in the input of UNPIVOT disappear in the output", eg

```
create table #t(id int, col_1 char(1), col_2 char(1), col_3 char(1))
insert into #t values (1,'A',null,'G')
insert into #t values (2,'A','c', null)

select  id, col, val 
from
  ( select * from #t ) p
unpivot
  ( Val for Col in (col_1, col_2, col_3 ) ) as unpvt
order by id, col;
```

In Synapse SQL On-Demand You can also do this by using FOR JSON / OPENJSON to pivot.

Like this

```
create table #t(id int, col_1 char(1), col_2 char(1), col_3 char(1))
insert into #t values (1,'A',null,'G')

select [key] columnName
from openjson(
(
 select * from #t
 where id = 1
 for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
)) d
where value is not null
and [key] <> 'id'
```

outputs

[image]

So Synapse SQL Pools (aka Azure SQL DW) should enentually get this too.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. However, this query doesn't work in Azure Synapse Pool/Azure SQL DW.  :(

Comment: That's bizzare...When I tried, it says incorrect syntax near 'for'. Is there any database settings I need to reconfigure in order to have your query work properly. It worked fine in Azure SQL DB though

Comment: Synapse SQL On-Demand is still in preview.  It's got some stuff that Synapse SQL Pools (aka Azure SQL Data Warehouse) doensn't have yet.  Looks like SQL Pools currently have OPENJSON but not FOR JSON.

Comment: You are correct. I tried using FOR XML Path and it also threw me same syntax error near for. Can this be achieved in Synapse SQL Pool

Comment: That helped me a lot. However, I was looking for a query that could handle columns dynamically . :)